# Разница в объявлении JS файла

Tags: javascript, html

Доброго времени суток !

Почему если объявить `JS` файл в начале кода `html`, некоторые функции не работают, а если в конце кода, то работают ?

Никогда с таким не сталкивался, а заметил только сейчас.

---

Вот пример подключения `JS` файла в начале кода:

```
<head>
    <title>Тайтл</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./js/main.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
/*

    Тут код

*/
</body>
```

Вот пример подключения `JS` файла в конце кода перед тегом `</body>`:

```
<head>
    <title>Тайтл</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
/*

    Тут код

*/
<script type="text/javascript" src="./js/main.js"></script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Было бы хорошо, конечно, если бы вы пример подключения показали.

> Почему если объявить js файл в начале кода html

Я так понимаю, вы подключаете его вначале тега `<body>` или в `<head>`? Скрипты грузятся синхронно. Если вы подключаете скрипт вначале html'а и обращаетесь к какому-то элементу, то, очевидно, такой скрипт работать не будет, так как элемента то такого ещё нет.

Когда вы подключаете скрипт в конце документа, все элементы DOM дерева к этому моменту уже подгружены, поэтому скрипт работает без проблем.

Comment: Спасибо, все разъяснили, я добавил пример кода !